# Using computer vision to comprehend Piping and Instrumentation Diagrams

Tags: computer-vision, object-recognition, graph-neural-networks

I'm wondering how to approach this problem. I want to create an excel document (or just a dictionary) where each instrument (circle objects FV 1031, for example) is associated with a line number (for example 2"-AL-131-14060-B4A2-IH).
[image] And also recognize line breaks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to find a good approach.